# How to deal with "String index out of range " in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm learning a bit of python and I'm doing the python workbook exercises . Right now I'm stuck on one called Tokenizing a String . I'm sure you know what that means . In my case the string must be a math equation and my code must tokenize it .
here is my code :

```
def tokenizer(x):
    x=x.replace(" ","")
    list = []
    j=0
    l=len(x)
    temp=""
    while j < len(x):
        if x[j] == "*" or x[j] == "/" or x[j] == "+" or x[j] == "-" or x[j] == "^" or x[j] == "(" or x[j] == ")":
            list.append(x[j])
            j=j+1
        while x[j]>="0" and x[j]<="9":
            temp = temp + x[j]
            while j<len(x):
                j=j+1
        if temp!="":
            list.append(temp)
            temp=""
    return list

def main():
    x=input("Enter math expression: ")
    list=tokenizer(x)
    print("the tokens are: ",list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So the problem is I can't find a solution where it is not running out of range . It all comes from that "while" loop . I tried the solution from the book , which was quite similar to my one , but it gives the same result . How can I avoid running out of range when I'm using while and adding to counter "j" in my case?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Can you give examples of what you would consider to be valid math expressions and their respective outputs? Also, you probably don't want to override the built-in *list* function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are adding 1 to `j` in this block:

```
while j < len(x):
    if x[j] == "*" or x[j] == "/" or x[j] == "+" or x[j] == "-" or x[j] == "^" or x[j] == "(" or x[j] == ")":
        list.append(x[j])
        j=j+1
    while x[j]>="0" and x[j]<="9":
        temp = temp + x[j]
        while j<len(x):
            j=j+1
    if temp!="":
        list.append(temp)
        temp=""
```

Let's say `j = len(x)-1` and the if statement evaluates to be `True`. This will execute the `j=j+1` statement.
Now when it enters the `while loop`, it checks whether `x[j]>="0"` but `x[j]` = `x[len(x)]`. Since we know that indexing starts at zero, for an array like

```
a = "abcd"
```

`len(a) = 4` but `a[4]` does not exist(last element is 3rd one) causing an `IndexError`.

Code with corrections:

```
def tokenizer(x):
    x=x.replace(" ","")
    list = []
    j=0
    l=len(x)
    temp=""
    while j < len(x):
        if x[j] == "*" or x[j] == "/" or x[j] == "+" or x[j] == "-" or x[j] == "^" or x[j] == "(" or x[j] == ")":
            list.append(x[j])
            print(x[j])
            print(list)
            j=j+1
        else: # Error 1: You code needs to execute this only if
              # the above condition fails
            j = j
            while j<len(x) and x[j].isnumeric(): # 2: You need to check both
                                                 # if the current character 
                                                 # is an integer and if 
                                                 # the index is out of range
                
                temp = temp + x[j]
                # while j<len(x)-1: No need for this statement
                j=j+1
            if temp!="":
                list.append(temp)
                temp=""
            
    return list

def main():
    x=input("Enter math expression: ")
    list=tokenizer(x)
    print("the tokens are: ",list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anshumaan . I understand that , but how can I avoid it ? I bashing my head in the desk for the last few hours now . Tried for loop tried to find some solution adding more conditions like if etc. . No matter what I do the last symbol in the string is always out of range . I'm sure there is some simple solution to that , I just can't think of it !

Comment: @GeorgiIvanov I have added the code

Comment: Thanks again man . I found out why my second solution worked and it is so simple . in the while loop the "j<len(x)" condition was last . When I put it first the first code works just fine as well :) . Had no idea this matters as well .

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but this works :

```
def tokenizer(x):
    x=x.replace(" ","")
    list = []
    j=0
    l=len(x)
    temp=""
    while j < len(x):
        if x[j] == "*" or x[j] == "/" or x[j] == "+" or x[j] == "-" or x[j] == "^" or x[j] == "(" or x[j] == ")":
            list.append(x[j])
            j=j+1
        while j<len(x) and x[j].isnumeric():
                temp=temp+x[j]
                j=j+1
        if temp!="":
            list.append(temp)
            temp=""

    return list

def main():
    x=input("Enter math expression: ")
    list=tokenizer(x)
    print("the tokens are: ",list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I change the " x[j]>="0" and x[j]<="9"" statement with .isnumeric() and for some weird reason it now works . For me both conditions are identical . Can anyone explain why this works ? I really want to learn how to overcome cases like that in future without loosing my sanity !!!

Thanks